# Howto test 32bit kernel specific syscall on a 64bit machine?

Tags: linux, system-calls

My question is quite specific. I have to write a simple program which works with files and should be run on arm 32bit (android). The crucial point is that it MUST use the _llseek syscall. This syscall exists in a 32bit linux kernel but is absent in a 64bit one.

Technically I can write and run this program on the arm device (phone in my case) but I do things on a 64bit box which I would normally use for tests and debugs. In this case my program fails to compile and run on my 64bit box due to the lack of this syscall.

What can be a workaround? I need some friendly test/debug environment. Is installing a 32bit virtual linux the only option?
Thanks in advance, Alex

---

The -m32 flag worked and indeed the 64bit kernel accepted the bytecode. Stupid enough that I did not come to this simple option myself, thanks.

Or put it differently. I did not notice that the 64bit kernel implements all 32bit calls in parallel, even those absent in the native 64bit code.

Comment: Is your 64 bits computer box an x86-64 or an ARM AARCH64?

Comment: On x86-64 but syscalls are essentially the same

Comment: 64 bits kernels implement 32 bits ABI and can execute 32 bits ELF executables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install an entire Linux 32 bits (x86/32 i.e. ia32) system in a partition -or simply a subdirectory- and run it under `chroot` in a 64 bits x86-64 Linux kernel (because 64 bits kernels for x86-64 are generally configured to be able to run 32 bits x86 code, that is to [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) a 32 bits x86 [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable binary) The `debootstrap` command (on Debian & related) is documenting such a use, see also `schroot` (you might not need to install every package in 32 bits chroot, only the relevant ones).

You can also use `gcc -m32` to compile to a 32 bits x86 ELF binary on a 64 bits x86-64 machine. You may need additional packages (often with `multilib` or `ia32` or `x86` in their name).

<sup>Of course you need to recompile the application since ARM is not the same as x86/32 bits</sup>

However, you cannot run an ARM 32 bits application (only a x86 32 bits one) on a 64 bits x86-64 Linux. To run an ARM application on x86, you need an [ARM emulator](http://www.thefreecountry.com/emulators/arm.shtml) (e.g. [qemu](http://qemu.weilnetz.de/qemu-doc.html#ARM-System-emulator)....)

So, debug first your thing on x86/32 bits using a 32 bits chroot-ed environment on your 64 bits x86-64 Linux system.

Comment: As long as the C/C++ code is identical, I compile it first for my native system (x86-64), then test/debug and then just recompile with the cross-compiler. It always worked. Before I met the problem in question.

Comment: You see, my wish is to avoid of installing an entire 32bit system for just one syscall. Is there a way to force an execution of a binary with just another kernel?

Comment: Well, `debootstrap`-ing is very easy. But you will use the same kernel, however 64 bits Linux kernels for x86-64 accept 32 bits x86 ELF executables and 32 bits syscalls.